# Lottery ticket odds

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Lets say that a scratch off has odds of 1 in 2.92 of winning. If I buy 3, do my odds of winning on at least 1 ticket change at all? For some reason I keep thinking that there is some tipping point when you buy at least 2.92 tickets (round up to 3), but I'm not sure that is true.

Comment: Odds change relative to or compared to what? Relative to buying 2, yes, the odds increase. Relative to buying 4, yes, the odds change as well, and they decrease. ... not sure what the question is here ...

Answer (score 0):

When you buy three, the probability of not winning at all is $(1-1/2.92)^3$. Hence, the probability of winning at least once is $1-(1-1/2.92)^3\approx0.7157$.

This is more than twice the probability of winning when you buy only one ticket (which is $1/2.92\approx0.3425$).

If you buy two tickets instead, then the probability of winning at least once becomes $1-(1-1/2.92)^2\approx0.5676$ which means around $66\%$ more chance of winning compared to the case with only one ticket.

If you buy $11$ tickets or more, the probability of winning at least once is more than $99\%$.

Answer (score 0):

Relative to buying less than 3 tickets, the odds of getting a winning ticket when you buy 3 will increase.

Relative to buying more than 3 tickets, the odds of getting a winning ticket when you buy 3 will decrease.

... but you knew that ...

Maybe your question is whether it becomes a certainty that you will win? No, it doesn't, just like throwing a die 6 times does not guarantee a 6, even if the chances of a 6 are 1 in 6.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the odds of winning on at least one ticket is simply the complement of the odds of losing on all tickets. Since the probability of losing one ticket is $1-\frac{1}{2.92}=\frac{1.92}{2.92}$ and the events of losing each ticket are independent from each other, the probability of losing them all is simply $\left(\frac{1.92}{2.92}\right)^3$ and thus the probability of winning at least one ticket if you buy three is:
$$1-\left(\frac{1.92}{2.92}\right)^3 \approx 71.57\%$$
Now, if you buy $n$ tickets, the probability is:
$$1-\left(\frac{1.92}{2.92}\right)^n$$
If you graph this, you'll see that the odds of winning a ticket always increase as you buy more tickets and the graph slowly approaches $1$, but never quite gets there, so there's no "tipping point" where buying some number of tickets makes it certain to win the lottery.

Answer (score 0):

If there are 73 lottery tickets, and 25 of them have a prize, then the 'tipping point' would be buying 49 of them.